# Problem with jquery function call

Tags: jquery

I am newbie with jquery and ajax. I have used a href to show and hide particular division with JQuery. In that div I am fetching records from database using ajax with some function. I don't know how to call that function on div on show.

Other option I have is on show button (that I used to view division) I call that function. But let me know how to call function on show button.

```
$('.childinfoshow').click(function() {
$(this).showchild(pgid); 
$(".childinfoshow").hide();
```

I have used this code but we above code I need to send pgid as argument and pgid is session value in php. How can I achieve both things.

Comment: A little snippet of your code would definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$('.childinfoshow').click(function() {
   showchild(pgid); 
   $(".childinfoshow").hide();
});
```

Comment: $('.childinfoshow').click(function() {
 $(this).showchild(pgid); 
$(".childinfoshow").hide();

Comment: Using jquery on click of class .childinfoshow I am disabling it at the same time I am calling function showchild(pgid). as I did in abouve code.

Comment: Its a self written function which is sending pgid(a php session variable value)  as argument.

Comment: @Aditii let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2979/discussion-between-shankarsangoli-and-aditii)